# Shuffling a Deck

Tags: java, methods, shuffle

I am working on a java experiment dealing with making a deck of cards. So far I believe I have a deck set up and now need to shuffle it. The way I am supposed to shuffle it is by by repeatedly (200 times) picking 2 cards randomly from the deck and switching them. I am still relatively new to Java and have never encountered anything like this before so I don't even know where to begin.

Can someone please help?

```
public class DeckOfCards {
```

Comment: Help with what, _specifically_? _I don't even know where to begin_ Stack Overflow would not be appropriate. We aren't a tutorial service. If you have a specific question for a specific problem, we may be able to help.

Comment: Sorry for making a bad post. I'm just not sure what kind of command or method would do what I am trying to do: pick two cards randomly and swap them x 200. I'm dumbfounded when it comes to thinking a way to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an array of Cards. To pick a random card, you can use [Random#nextInt(int)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt(int)). It will pick a random number between 0 and the parameter you pass it. Using this you just pick two random cards and swap them in the array.

```
public final Random random = new Random();

public void shuffle() {
    for(int i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
        int firstCardIndex = random.nextInt(number - 1);
        int secondCardIndex = random.nextInt(number - 1);

        Card firstCard = deck[firstCardIndex];
        Card secondCard = deck[secondCardIndex];

        deck[firstCardIndex] = secondCard;
        deck[secondCardIndex] = firstCard;
    }
}
```

There are some common shuffling algorithms. I've used the [Fisher-Yates Shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) before.

Answer (score 1):

I did not understand your problem clearly. But may be you want to do something like this(not sure) - Here I am shuffling the deck 5 times and each time I am picking up two cards randomly from the deck.

```
public void display() {
     String[] ranks = {"Ace", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "Jack", "Queen", "King"};
     String[] suits = {"Clubs", "Diamonds", "Hearts", "Spades"};

     List<String> list1=new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(ranks));
     List<String> list2=new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(suits));

     int times=1;
     while(times<=5){
         Collections.shuffle(list1);
         Collections.shuffle(list2);
         Random r=new Random();
         int i=r.nextInt(3);
         int j=r.nextInt(3);
         int k=r.nextInt(12);
         int m=r.nextInt(12);
         System.out.println("For "+times+" time you picked up "+list1.get(k)+
                 " of "+list2.get(i)+" and "+list1.get(m)+ " of "+list2.get(j));
         times++;
     }
}
```

In the main method just call the "display" function.